# Why does windows allow to create private heap?

Tags: windows, memory-management, heap-memory

I am learning memory managment in Windows. I know that process in windows has by default its heap, that can be extended in future. Also process can create additional (private) heaps. Why does windows allow to create private heap? What is benefit of such approach? As I understand usage of default heap (with possible reallocations) is enough. Or maybe is it another way to optimize reallocations?

Comment: Being able to call `HeapDestroy` to instantly deallocate everything you don't need anymore (as opposed to doing a costly walk to free objects individually) is one big benefit. Or, as [an article on MSDN puts it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms810603), "[...] one nice benefit of heap memory is how well it caters to the needs of traditional data structures such as binary trees, linked lists, and dynamic arrays. Having the heap handle provides a way of uniquely identifying these structures independently.".

Comment: [Here's a story](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2006/02/02/unmanaged-memory-fragmentation-an-old-story/) that shows how private heaps were used in a real-world scenario: Reducing thread contention, and reducing fragmentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [`HeapCreate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599(v=vs.85).aspx) you will see that it has multiple options that changes how the heap works. `HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE` will make it faster but you have to handle thread synchronization on your own etc.

Having multiple heaps can also be beneficial if you allocate objects of different sizes with different lifetimes. You might want to put large long-living objects on their own heap if you also have a high churn of small objects that are allocated and de-allocated as part of your work to reduce fragmentation (and lock contention if you are multithreaded).

As noted in a comment, you can call `HeapDestroy` to free every allocation and the heap itself in one call but this only makes sense if you have full control over everything allocated there. You are not allowed to destroy the default heap so you must create your own private heap to use this trick.